# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_BlogCommentReply_BlogCommentId"

Tags: sql

I have a blog and keeping it simple for discussion, the main tables are Blog, BlogComment, BlogCommentReply and User.

A blog belongs to a User.
A comment belongs to a blog/user.
A comment reply belongs to a blog/comment/user.

I want to delete a User - UserId = 5.

My delete user stored procedure deletes (wrapped in a transaction) in this order:

- BlogCommentReply
- BlogComment
- Blog (if the user is the author of the blog only)
- User

It deletes the entry(s) in the BlogCommentReply for the User, then attempts to delete the entry(s) in the BlogComment for the User.

I then get the error:

```
   The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_BlogCommentReply_BlogCommentId". 
   The conflict occurred in database "DBGbngDev", table "dbo.BlogCommentReply", column 
   'BlogCommentId'.
```

It still thinks there is an entry in the BlogCommentReply table.

---

Here is the execute of the stored procedure with debug selects in it to show that it deletes the BlogCommentReply entry but then fails on the delete of the BlogComment.

[image]
[image]

---

Table definitions:

```
----------------------- BlogComment table (parent to blogCommentReply)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BlogComment](
    [BlogCommentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BlogId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BlogCommentContent] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [LikeCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DisLikeCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeOfBlogComment] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BlogComment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BlogCommentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogComment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogComment_BlogId] FOREIGN 
KEY([BlogId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Blog] ([BlogId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogComment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogComment_BlogId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogComment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogComment_UserId] FOREIGN 
KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogComment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogComment_UserId]
GO

----------------------- BlogCommentReply table (child)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BlogCommentReply](
    [BlogCommentReplyId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BlogCommentId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BlogId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BlogCommentReplyContent] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [LikeCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DisLikeCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeOfBlogCommentReply] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_BlogCommentReply] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BlogCommentReplyId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogCommentReply] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogCommentReply_BlogCommentId] 
FOREIGN KEY([BlogCommentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BlogComment] ([BlogCommentId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogCommentReply] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogCommentReply_BlogCommentId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogCommentReply]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogCommentReply_BlogId] FOREIGN 
KEY([BlogId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Blog] ([BlogId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogCommentReply] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogCommentReply_BlogId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogCommentReply]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogCommentReply_UserId] FOREIGN 
KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogCommentReply] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogCommentReply_UserId]
GO
```

---

Extracted parts of the delete stored procedure (@a_UserId = 5):

```
                    --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++       
                    -- Step 6. Get the number of blog comments replys for the user.
                    -- Note: there may not be any. 
                    --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                    SELECT @BlogCommentReplysCount = Count(*)
                    FROM dbo.BlogCommentReply
                    WHERE ( UserId = @a_UserId )

                    SELECT @ReturnCode = @@ERROR

                    IF @ReturnCode <> 0
                        BEGIN 
                            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

                            SELECT @Message =  'Critical Error - procedure DeleteBlog failed during the select of BlogCommentReply. User id: ' + CAST(@a_UserId AS VARCHAR) + '. '
                            RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
                    END

                    SELECT '@BlogCommentReplysCount: ' + CAST(@BlogCommentReplysCount AS VARCHAR) + '. '

                    --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++       
                    -- Step 7. Delete the BlogCommentReply entries for the user.        
                    -- Note: the user may not have made any.                                 
                    --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                    DELETE dbo.BlogCommentReply
                    WHERE ( UserId = @a_UserId )
         
                    SELECT @ReturnCode = @@ERROR,
                           @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

                    IF @ReturnCode <> 0 AND @RowCount > 0
                        BEGIN
                            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

                            SELECT @Message =  'Critical Error - procedure DeleteBlog failed during the delete of BlogCommentReply. User id: ' + CAST(@a_UserId AS VARCHAR) + '. '
                                RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
                    END
                           
                   SELECT 'Deleted BlogCommentReply'
                   SELECT '@ReturnCode: ' + CAST(@ReturnCode AS VARCHAR) + '. '
                   SELECT '@RowCount: ' + CAST(@RowCount AS VARCHAR) + '. '
                   SELECT '@a_UserId: ' + CAST(@a_UserId AS VARCHAR) + '. '

                   SELECT Count(*) as AFTERDELETE
                   FROM dbo.BlogCommentReply
                   WHERE ( UserId = @a_UserId )

                   --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++        
                   -- Step 8. Get the number of blog comments for this user.
                   -- Note: there may not be any. 
                   --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                   SELECT @BlogCommentsCount = Count(*)
                   FROM dbo.BlogComment
                   WHERE ( UserId = @a_UserId )

                   SELECT @ReturnCode = @@ERROR

                    IF @ReturnCode <> 0
                        BEGIN 
                            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

                            SELECT @Message =  'Critical Error - procedure DeleteBlog failed during the select of BlogComment. User id: ' + CAST(@a_UserId AS VARCHAR) + '. '
                            RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
                    END

                   SELECT '@BlogCommentsCount: ' + CAST(@BlogCommentsCount AS VARCHAR) + '. '

                    --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++       
                    -- Step 9. Delete the BlogComment entries for the user. 
                    -- Note: the user may not have made any.                                     
                    --+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                    SELECT Count(*) as BEFORE
                    FROM dbo.BlogComment
                    WHERE ( UserId = @a_UserId )

                    SELECT  'Going to delete BlogComment'

                    DELETE dbo.BlogComment
                    WHERE ( UserId = @a_UserId )
         
                    SELECT @ReturnCode = @@ERROR,
                                    @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

                    IF @ReturnCode <> 0 AND @RowCount > 0
                        BEGIN
                            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

                            SELECT @Message =  'Critical Error - procedure DeleteBlog failed during the delete of BlogComment. User id: ' + CAST(@a_UserId AS VARCHAR) + '. '
                            RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
                    END
                    
                   SELECT  'Deleted BlogComment'
```

Comment: Could you post the complete procure? There are just two delete statements in the script you've written here.

Comment: My guess would be that the stored procedure deletes BlogCommentReplies for the given UserId only, then attepts to delete a BlogComment that still has a BlogCommentReply attached to it for another UserId

Comment: Fuzzy...that's it. How do I give you credit?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to have your complete stored procedure script to check the error, but for the mean time I guess the problem is here:

```
DELETE dbo.BlogCommentReply
WHERE ( UserId = @a_UserId )
```

Ok, it's deleting all of comment replies which the related user (i.e. @a_UserId = 5) has.

But look at the rest of your script:

```
DELETE dbo.BlogComment
WHERE ( UserId = @a_UserId )
```

It's deleting all of user's comments, WHILE they may have some other comment replies for another users and they are not deleted. So I think the problem is here.

Maybe it's better to change the first deletion part to:

```
DELETE dbo.BlogCommentReply
WHERE ( UserId = @a_UserId )

DELETE dbo.BlogCommentReply
FROM [dbo].[BlogComment]
WHERE  dbo.BlogCommentReply.BlogCommentId=[dbo].[BlogComment].BlogCommentId
AND [dbo].[BlogComment].UserId=@a_UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple you are deleting comment's reply of a specific user while other users might have reply under the same comment.
I you really want to delete all related info of a user , you have to go with different approach like finding all replies under that user's comment and delete those.